# Single Inheritance in C# - object class?

Tags: c#

I have been asking myself this question for a long time now. Thought of posting it. C# doesn't support Multiple Inheritance(this is the fact). All classes created in C# derive out of 'Object' class(again a fact).

So if C# does not support Multiple inheritance, then how are we able to extend a class even though it already extends Object class?

Illustating with an example:

1. class A : object - Class A created.
2. class B : object - Class B created.
3. class A : B - this again is supported. What happens to the earlier association to object.

We are able to use object class methods in A after step 3. So is the turned to multi level inheritance. If that is the case, then

1. class A : B
2. class C : B
3. class A : C - I must be able to access class B's methods in A. Which is not the case?

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Joel's answer is correct. There is a difference between multiple inheritance and an inhertance tree (or derivation chain). In your example, you actually show an inhertance tree: One object inherits (derives) from another object higher in the tree. Multiple inheritance allows one object to inherit from multiple base classes.

Take, for example, the following tree:

```
public class BaseClass { }

public class SpecialBaseClass : BaseClass {}

public class SpecialtyDerivedClass : SpecialBaseClass {}
```

This is perfectly valid and says that SpecialtyDerivedClass inherits from SpecialBaseClass (SpecialtyDerivedClass' parent) which, in turn, derives from BaseClass (SpecialtyDerivedClass' grandparent).

Under the idea of multiple inheritance, the example would look like this:

```
public class BaseClass { }

public class SpecialBaseClass {}

public class SpecialtyDerivedClass : BaseClass, SpecialBaseClass {}
```

This is not allowed in .NET, but it says that SpecialityDerivedClass inherits from both BaseClass and SpecialBaseClass (which are both parents).

.NET does allow a form of multiple inheritance by allowing you to inherit from more than one interface. Changing the example above slightly:

```
public class BaseClass { }

public interface ISpecialBase {}

public interface ISpecialDerived {}

public class SpecialtyDerivedClass : BaseClass, ISpecialBase, ISpecialDerived {}
```

This says that SpecialtyDerivedClass inherits from BaseClass (it's parent) and also ISpecialBase and ISpecialDerived (also parent's but more like step-parents as interfaces can't specify functionality).

Comment: My confusion was that I failed to see that System.Object class becomes a grand parent after the inheritance of A : B. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7):

You're confusing mutliple inheritance with an inheritance tree.  You can inherit from something other than Object.  It's just that Object is sitting way up there at the top of your tree.  And someone can inherit your class, but because Object is still up there at the top that class will also inherit from object.  Your "Multi-level" inheritance is not multiple inheritance.

Multiple inheritance is when you inherit from two different trees, and .Net actually does support this after a fashion via interfaces.

Comment: C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, but it does support multiple interfaces. You can still only inherit from 1 object only.

Comment: It's just semantics.  Implementing an interface _is_ a weak form of inheritance.

Comment: Substitute "branch of a tree" for tree and skip the part about implementing interfaces being inheritance.  Implementing an interface just means that your class guarantees that it will define a signature. You don't inherit any code from an interface.  But, you said "after a fashion", so, I guess...

Comment: I have to back up Mark on this.  It is important to distinguish implementation from extension.  Implementing an interface is agreeing to a contract.  It is not inheritance in the OOP sense of the word.

Comment: Also, structs implement interfaces, but they do not do any inheritance. Value types "derive from" rather than "inherit" their superclass (System.ValueType). Because of this, implementing an interface is not really like inheritance at all.

Comment: Implementing an interface isn't inheritance unless it's possible to inherit from a person with no assets.

Answer (score 4):

All classes *ultimately* derive from Object.

```
public class A
```

is implicitly equivalent to

```
public class A : System.Object
```

When you derive from another class

```
public class A : B
```

where

```
public class B : System.Object
```

B becomes the parent class, and Object becomes the grandparent class.

And so on.

So it is the parent, grandparent, great-grandparent (etc) class of all other classes.

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at it is this: C# has an inheritance *tree*, while C++ (or other muliple-inheritance languages) has an inheritance *lattice*.

Answer (score 0):

Given below.

```
public class A : B
{

}

public class B : C
{
    public int BProperty { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int CProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public void TestStuff()
    {
        A a = new A();

        // These are valid.
        a.CProperty = 1;
        a.BProperty = 2;
    }

}
```

This is valid.  Object is a base for C in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the reason that B can extend A is because A extends Object. A class can only specify one parent class, but that class must either be object or have object as one of its ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

A class inherits from object **if you do not specify a base class**. Thus:

```
class C {}
```

is the same as

```
class C : Object {}
```

However, **if you specify a base class, it will inherit from that class instead of Object**. Thus,

```
class B : C {}
```

B directly inherits from C instead of Object. Another example,

```
class A : B {}
```

In this case, A inherits from B instead of Object. To summarize, in this hierarchy:

```
class C {}
class B : C {}
class A : B {}
```

Class A derives from B, which derives from C. So Class A is indirectly derived from C because B is derived from C. C also derived from Object which in not explicitly specified but it is there by default. So A is indirectly derived from Object too.

Comment: A class will always ultimately inherit from object, even when you specify your own base class.

Comment: Yes - ultimately - but not directly. I think I've explained that on the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

A class in C# can only have one parent, but it can have multiple ancestors.  You can implement multiple interfaces, but that only means that your class agrees to implement the signatures defined by those interfaces.  You don't actually inherit any functionality from those interfaces.